K8 Ingress using nginx is returning 404
I have the following files:
Ingress Definition
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
        kind: Ingress
        metadata:
          name: app-api-ingress
          namespace: default
          labels:
            io.kompose.service: app-api-ingress
        spec:
          ingressClassName: nginx
          rules:
          - host: api.studio
            http:
              paths:
              - path: /auth(/|$)(.*)
                pathType: ImplementationSpecific
                backend:
                  service:
                    name: studio-auth-api
                    port:
                      number: 8080
              - path: /aggregator(/|$)(.*)
                pathType: ImplementationSpecific
                backend:
                  service:
                    name: studio-api
                    port:
                      number: 8080

Service Definition
apiVersion: v1
    kind: Service
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\kubernetes-kompose\tools\kompose.exe convert -f Studio/docker-compose.yml -o ./k8s/
        kompose.version: 1.32.0 (765fde254)
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: studio-auth-api
      name: studio-auth-api
    spec:
      type: NodePort 
      ports:
        - name: "http"
          port: 8080
          targetPort: 8080
          nodePort: 30251
      selector:
        io.kompose.service: studio-auth-api

Deployment Definition
apiVersion: apps/v1
    kind: Deployment
    metadata:
      annotations:
        kompose.cmd: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\kubernetes-kompose\tools\kompose.exe convert -f Studio/docker-compose.yml -o ./k8s/
        kompose.version: 1.32.0 (765fde254)
      labels:
        io.kompose.service: studio-auth-api
      name: studio-auth-api
    spec:
      replicas: 1
      selector:
        matchLabels:
          io.kompose.service: studio-auth-api
      template:
        metadata:
          annotations:
            kompose.cmd: C:\ProgramData\chocolatey\lib\kubernetes-kompose\tools\kompose.exe convert -f Studio/docker-compose.yml -o ./k8s/
            kompose.version: 1.32.0 (765fde254)
            dapr.io/enabled: "true"
            dapr.io/app-id: "studio-auth-api"
            dapr.io/app-port: "8080"
          labels:
            io.kompose.network/studio-default: "true"
            io.kompose.service: studio-auth-api
        spec:
          containers:
            - env:
                - name: ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT
                  value: Production
              image: studioauthapi
              livenessProbe:
                exec:
                  command:
                    - curl --fail http://localhost:80/health || exit 1
                failureThreshold: 3
                periodSeconds: 30
                timeoutSeconds: 30
              name: studio-auth-api
              ports:
                - containerPort: 8080
                  hostPort: 1251
                  protocol: TCP
          restartPolicy: Always


The pods are running (and Dapr sidecars)
The auth service is accessible by using IP:30251/auth/whatever
There are no errors in pod logs
The service has endpoints
Ingress is loaded when checked
Nginx controller is running

I am trying to call out to api.studio/auth/whatever and all I get is:

With the logs looking like this:

Service "default/studio-auth-api" does not have any active Endpoint.

Can anyone help with this?

I posted this question a little prematurely. I was missing the rewrite annotation in the Ingress definition:
annotations:
                nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2

